# Rebus saga data state issue

Tags: rebus

I'm trying out the simple deferred message timeout pattern in Rebus along the outline here http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/3043 in order to have alternative behaviors depending on whether or not I receive a timely response from an other service hooked up to the same bus. Code has been modified to use async/await.
(yes, I know that article is really about unit testing. I'm just trying out the same timeout thing)

The handler in my case is a saga. Two message send operations are awaited as the last two calls of the handler of the message that starts the saga. First message uses request/reply from the external service and the reply is also eventually handled in the same saga. 
Second message is a deferred message that is supposed to enforce the alternative action in case timeout occurs, just like in the Rebus unit test example. I've verified that messages are sent from and received by the saga/handler without any problems. It looks something like this:

```
public class TestSaga : Saga<TestSagaData>, IAmInitiatedBy<SomeMessage>, IHandleMessages<SomeReply>, IHandleMessages<TimeOutMessage>
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;
    public TestSaga(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    protected override void CorrelateMessages(ICorrelationConfig<TestSagaData> config)
    {
        config.Correlate<SomeMessage>(s => s.Identifier, d => d.OriginalMessageIdentifier);
        config.Correlate<SomeMessage>(s => s.Tag, d => d.CorrelationIdentifier);
        config.Correlate<SomeReply>(s => s.Tag, d => d.CorrelationIdentifier);
        config.Correlate<TimeOutMessage>(s => s.Tag, d => d.CorrelationIdentifier);
    }

    public async Task Handle(SomeMessage message)
    {
        if (!IsNew)
            return;

        Data.CorrelationIdentifier = message.Tag;
        Data.OriginalMessageIdentifier = message.Identifier;
        Data.ReplyReceived = false;
        await _bus.Send(new SomeRequest {Tag = message.Tag});
        await _bus.Defer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), new TimeOutMessage() {Tag = message.Tag});
    }

    public async Task Handle(SomeReply message)
    {
        // Even if we would get here loooong before...
        Data.ReplyReceived = true;
        await DoStuffIfNotTimedout();
    }

    public async Task Handle(TimeOutMessage message)
    {
        // ...this, DoStuffIfTimeout below is always called
        // since state is preserved from the _bus.Defer call. Correct?
        if (!Data.ReplyReceived)
            await DoStuffIfTimedout();
    }

    private async Task  DoStuffIfNotTimedout()
    {
        // some more async stuff here            
        MarkAsComplete();
    }

    private async Task DoStuffIfTimedout()
    {
        // some more async stuff here
        MarkAsComplete();
    }
}
```

I have added a boolean saga data flag/property to indicate that the reply to the first message was received first, setting it to false initially before the both await Send/Defer calls 
and setting it to true immediately in the message handler of the reply. 
The flag was supposed to be used to prevent the timeout actions to start in case the deferred timeout thing was received after the first reply but before the subsequent actions were done with and the saga marked completed.

However, in this case the state of the saga seems to 'follow' the message received. So if the first message reply handler is entered first and sets the saga data flag to true. Then when the deferred message handler is entered later, 
something has reset the flag again, seemingly ignoring the action taken in the first reply handler (setting the flag true). Not sure whether the 'Revision' number of the saga is supposed to change or not but it remains unchanged (zero) all the time it seems.
Also noted that it doesn't matter if the timeout occurs long after the reply handler is entered, when the timeout handler is entered, the the flag is 'false'.

Is this saga state behavior by design? I thought saga state would somehow be persisted between message handler calls. If it's the wrong behavior, what could possibly cause it?
I quite new to Rebus so I'm sure I've misunderstood something here but in that case I would like to know what :).

Transport used under the hood is RabbitMQ.

Test code: [saga state test](https://github.com/petkit/rebustest.git)